# Python: Using schedule class with Tkinter (multi-threading)

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, schedule

I have 2 programs. One which uses the schedule library, the other which uses Tkinter. I wish to run the scheduling program once Tkinter is launched. Any ideas?

This is the Scheduling test code:

```
import schedule
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime


class testSchedule:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main()

    def printing(self):
        print(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M'))

    def main(self):
        schedule.every(1).minutes.do(self.printing)
        while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testSchedule()
```

This is the Tkinter code:

```
from tkinter import *
from testSchedule import *


class test:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Test")
        frame = LabelFrame(root, text="Test frame", padx = 5, pady=5)
        frame.pack()
        b = Button(frame, text="Test")
        b.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry('425x250')
    application = test(root)
    testSchedule()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want to schedule tasks then you should look into `.after()` in Tkinter.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the suggestion! I have updated the question. My program is more complicated than the test programs I have put up. I don't think .after() would help me. Do you have any other suggestions?